# Spotify web api to play playlists

Tags: artificial-intelligence, spotify

I'm building a voice activated AI system for my home.  A la Echo, I want to be able to start streaming music on my android host when I say "play some rock".  I can handle the ai part, but I need a web API endpoint to start streaming music.

Comment: I use https://www.mopidy.com/ for this purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's [Web API Endpoint Reference](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/endpoint-reference/). This Web API endpoints gives external applications access to Spotify catalog and user data. And some [Web API Code Examples & Libraries](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/code-examples/) and here's [Working With Playlists](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/working-with-playlists/).

Also have a look at [this](https://github.com/zmb3/spotify). This repo is a Go wrapper for working with Spotify's Web API which aims to support every task listed in the [Web API Endpoint Reference](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/endpoint-reference/).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The [Mopidy music server](https://www.mopidy.com/) can stream music from spotify and offers lots of API options for clients.